# Transparent icon has white background in Visual Studio C++ executable

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, exe

In my Visual Studio 2019 C++ project created as Empty Project (C++, Windows, Console), I added an Icon resource and it is being displayed as the icon of the executable since it is the only icon in the project.

The image is in `*.ico` format and has a transparent background. When it is displayed as the icon of the executable on the desktop, it has a white background.

How do I set a transparent icon as the icon of the executable produced by a Visual Studio 2019 C++ project configured with the Windows SubSystem?

I am using the executable from the `Release` folder.
The project is very simple, it has a single `*.cpp` file.

Comment: Using transparent icon as executable icon does not require any special actions. Perhaps something is wrong with the icon itself. ¿Is it displayed properly in Windows Explorer?

Comment: It seems to depend on the size of the icons displayed on the desktop. Try Ctrl+Mousescroll to change the size. My icon is black - and sometimes transparent

Comment: Does your .ico file contain a single icon size or multiple icon sizes? Microsoft [recommends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/vis-icons#size-requirements) including at least 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, and 256x256 for app icons. Maybe the background becomes white the deskop icon size differs from what you provided in your .ico file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the Windows thumbnail cache. Initially I had used a fully-opaque image, and when I used the same image but with a transparent background, Windows Explorer was showing the old cached one.

I cleared the thumbnail cache via Disk Cleanup.